# Another phrase for "wear and tear inspection" of tools and equipment report

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that could substitute "wear and tear" in a resumé.

The original was:

> "Wear and tear inspection reports for the preliminary maintenance of tools and equipment."

I had found:

> depletion, depreciation, erosion, ablation, attrition, consumption, decrement, dissipation, hard wear, overuse, ravages of time, wearing away, and weathering.

(None of them quite fit since I was talking about offshore drilling tools and equipment. In this case "upkeep" deals with the concept in a better way.)

Comment: In what context? What is the sentence/fragment which currently mentions *wear and tear* which you would like to change?

Comment: As a list item on the description of tasks executed. It became "Upkeep inspection reports for the preliminary maintenance of tools and equipment."

Comment: So which word replaced *wear and tear*?

Comment: Your sentence as replaced sounds odd to this native American English speaker.  If it were me, I would swap upkeep and maintain.  "Maintain inspection reports for the preliminary upkeep of tools and equipment."  Its just my opinion, but upkeep as a verb in your sentence just feels *off.*

Comment: Unless the snippet provided is a sentence fragment, and "upkeep inspection report" is a compound subject rather than a verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on context, if you are discussing *dealing with wear and tear* of equipment, you might consider

> - maintenance
> - upkeep
> - service
> - overhaul
> - repair
> - conservation
> - support

**SUPPLEMENT**

In light of your edit, also consider *condition*.

Comment: Upkeep did it. Kudos.

Comment: Upkeep is not a substitute for "wear and tear". The words in the list above are words that can refer to how tool degradation (wear and tear) is minimized or reversed.

Comment: @Jim None of the words are actually synonyms for *wear and tear* but try to get to what I thought was the implied concept of prevention or correction of normal wear.

Comment: Sort of turns SE into a bizarre mess, if you ask me. So I had to point it out. I recommend that someone reword the question, then.

Comment: @Jim You got it. It's been reworded.

Comment: @SurvMach you need to add @ in front of the username in order to notify the person.

Comment: @SurvMach You need to consider how your accepted answer is consistent with the updated question. (It's not.) You're asking about one thing, X, and accepting words describing the mitigation of X as your answer. (Strong hints are in this comment.)

Comment: @Jim Can't but agree with you.

Comment: The implications of the author accepting this answer given the question could bring down everything that we believe in!

Comment: @RyeBread The true language has more meaning in our tone, body, and face. So my answers won't focus on what someone else said. Everything will come, straight from my head. (Not all questions and answers will tend to your standards. But then again, why let other people communicate huh?)

Comment: @SurvMach - I don't know how to respond... I was being sarcastic before.  Thought your question was fine.

Comment: @RyeBread I suspected it. And here I am, looking like an idiot. Again. (long story)

Answer (score 1):

I actually think the expression **wear and tear** is the best one to use in the OP's résumé. It is recognized in legal contracts and it is commonly understood by all, the layman included.

But the OP could rephrase his original sentence to:

> Responsible for monitoring the **performance** of tools and equipment.

This would include reporting any signs of poor performance due to:

- *deterioration*
- *corrosion*
- *wear*
- *consumption* 

  and
- *aging*